# Drupal 8 entity query with multiple taxonomy terms

Tags: drupal, drupal-taxonomy

I have a Drupal 8 content entity with a relation to a taxonomy term which allows multiple values. 
I want to query the entity and get content that has only the terms I use in the query. 
The problem is I could not find a way to query my entity with multiple taxonomy terms and get the content that are associated with them.

My content entity (node bundle) is called "cocktails" and has among others an entity reference field called "field_ingredients" that has a relation to the taxonomy Vocabulary "Ingredients". 
I want to get the entity that has for example 2 ingredients with the taxonomy ids: 40 AND 35. I tried the following code without success:

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
$query->condition('type', 'cocktails');
$query->condition('field_ingredients.entity.tid', 40);
$query->condition('field_ingredients.entity.tid', 35);
$node_ids = $query->execute();
```

$node_ids are 0

And also this:

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
$query->condition('type', 'cocktails');
$query->condition('field_ingredients.entity.tid', array(40, 35), 'IN');
$node_ids = $query->execute();
```

$node_ids are 3 which returns the node ids that have one of the two taxonomy ids (OR logic),

The right answer should be one node id, which is the node that is related to both taxonomy ids, the cocktail with both ingredients

Answer (score 6):

Finally the solution was posted in the actual Drupal API Documentation as a comment

```
$query->condition(
    $query
        ->andConditionGroup()
        ->condition('field_ingredients', [40, 35,])
    )
);
```

look at the following link for more details:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!Query!QueryInterface.php/function/QueryInterface%3A%3AandConditionGroup/8.2.x

on the first comment and first example ("WORKING code")

Comment: The code in your answer and the in the link are slightly different. In your answer, you are binding multiple values with the array to a single parameter. This will result in an SQL error about the number of bound parameters. The correct answer is in the link, where you must loop through every tag ID and bind them one by one (instead of where you have the array). Still giving an upvote, since I would not have found that answer you linked to on my own.